# Initialize a tree in inorder?

Tags: c++, initializer-list, tree-traversal

Im using initializer list and helper to create a tree in inorder. for example {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} if I print the tree in inorder traversal it will also give 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

```
tree::tree(const initializer_list<int>& I) {
    const int* p1 = I.begin();
    root = nullptr;
    IL_helper(I, p1, root);
}

void tree::IL_helper(const initializer_list<int>& I, const int*& p1, node* & p2) {
    if (p1 == I.end()) {
        return;
    }
    
    p2 = new node(*p1);
    ++p1;
    
    IL_helper(I, p1, p2->Lchild);
    IL_helper(I, p1, p2->Rchild);
}
```

how to form a tree with inorder traversal with recursion. In my code, I realize it will only have Lchild.
tree t{1,2,3,4,5,6,7} ;
cout << t.inOrderT(t.root);
output: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p2 = new node(*p1);`

overwrites the `p2`, but its type is just `node*`, so this assignment does not affect anything outside of the function. Just change the parameter to `node* &p2`.

Also, I see a second problem - in your example is no bisection of the input list - so the nodes of the tree you will construct will always have just the `Lchild` set. Because in the recursive chain of `IL_helper(I, p1, p2->Lchild);` all of the list will be consumed, leaving nothing left for the Rchild call. It's technically not a bug if that's the intended behavior ( for example, the tree might be re-balanced afterwards ), but is it ?

Comment: yes after I change the p2 I realize that I only have Lchild. Is there anyway to fix this ?

Comment: Recursion and trees don't go well together. The main reason for Recursion is to save some "memory" by encoding important state in the call stack and not in custom state variables. But this I exactly what you need to change to fix this issue. Thus, Recursion will simply not be your solution. Basically you have to fill all the leaves of one depth simultaneously....

Comment: Recursion and trees go together *extremely well* - just change the algorithm so that it reads the entire sequence first, split it like *lower half* - *middle point* - *upper half*. And then keep the middle point for the parent and  give the first half to the Lchild and the second half to the Rchild and then apply this recursively until you have nothing left to give to the kids